# Incremental issue with creating histogram (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, histogram, increment

Using the code below I am trying to create histograms of the values in each row of `dist`, where each row of `hist` is a histogram of 10 bins. 
`step` is a floating point value (0.12158...).

```
 for(i = 0; i < dist.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < dist[0].length; j++){
        bin = parseInt(dist[i][j]/step);
        if(bin == 10)
            bin = 9;
        hist[i][bin]+=1;
    }
}
```

`dist` is a 2D array declared as:

```
var dist = [];
for(var x = 0; x < 77; x++){
    dist[x] = [];    
    for(var y = 0; y < 50; y++){ 
        dist[x][y] = x*y;    
    }    
}
```

`hist` is similarly declared as:

```
var hist = [];
for(var x = 0; x < 77; x++){
    hist[x] = [];    
    for(var y = 0; y < 10; y++){ 
        hist[x][y] = x*y;    
    }    
}
```

The first row of `hist` gives me the results I would expect, with the frequencies totalling 50. However, the values in the bins of the next rows do not start from zero, so the values of these are the sum of the values from the previous histograms plus the current value.

For example, the first row of `hist`:

```
[1, 10, 8, 9, 6, 7, 4, 3, 1, 1]
```

The second row of `hist`:

```
[1, 10, 10, 13, 10, 12, 10, 9, 10, 10]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want `dist[0]` in `for(j = 0; j < dist[0].length; j++){` ? Or ought that be `dist[i]`?

Comment: The length of the rows doesn't change so that doesn't make a difference in this case

Comment: Your bin calculation `bin = parseInt(dist[i][j]/step);` can be greater than 10 and your testing for equal 10. Please have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/21xtkyrg/). I'm not sure if this will fix your problem. But the bin is then of length 10.

Comment: @AWolf Thanks for pointing that out! It didn't solve the main issue but that is helpful.